# Is it possible to predict based on arbitrary attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling

I have a job/task runner system that takes a task description as input from a queue and delegates it to a machine on which to run. Based on the task type and other properties, some which are task-specific, the machine will change what it does (i.e. which app it runs). Each machine runs one task at a time. We send all tasks to a large sized machine right now which can handle anything we throw at it. This works fine, but wastes resources for smaller tasks.

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to predict the best class of machine on which to run a particular task, based on the task descriptor, so we can send wimpy tasks to a wimpy machine and tough ones to a more powerful machine, without needing to manually classify them ahead of time. The descriptors are JSON objects with a task type (app name) and "arbitrary" criteria, specific to that type of task. Various timing differences can affect the resources needed (time of day, week of year, etc.) even for the same task type (i.e. task A at the end of a quarter might take twice the ram as it did the week before).

I took a couple intro to ML courses 10+ years ago. Currently I am exploring ML.NET's text classification, though I feel like an ANN might work as well. Essentially I want a system that can recognize "if it's task A on week Y with criteria Z etc., it should go on a large machine" without predetermining all these heuristics.

One complication is that each task can have different criteria. Most are strings, and can be sparse (empty/null values are normal). An empty criteria is important and shouldn't just be ignored (e.g. it means process all items, not just one). Even if I split into models per-task-type this will be the case, though maybe easier to make accurate.

Another is that some attributes are negative indicators, e.g. if a job uses over 90% memory, crashed/errored or was otherwise unsuccessful, it should be considered "bad" and a larger machine used instead. I'm not sure how to represent or account for this though so that, when combined with the other attributes, a similar task would run on a larger machine. Maybe I could find these failed jobs, bump up the vm size, and train it that way, to nudge it upwards.

The idea is that for new tasks it would run the descriptor through a service and receive the (hopefully) best machine size to run it on, and after it runs/fails, train again to get more accurate.

Is there any algorithm or methodology that would be more applicable to this sort of problem?